# how to get data from object in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
View Code:

 <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md">
            Pizza List - {{$id}}
        </div> 
        {{$p->type}}  // This is not working.Here I only want to print type of pizza from the 
                         db.ERROR 
                            =Property [type] does not exist on this collection instance.
        {{$p}}  // But This Does shows Data in JSON.
    </div>


Controller Code:

public function show($id){

        $p=Pizza::where('p_name','prashant')->get();

        return view('details',['id'=>$id,'p'=>$p]);
    }
```

Here I want to fetch the Type of pizza order by person having column name p_name in db so i have given some static name. I'm just a beginner. Can Anyone tell me what to do to print only pizza type

Comment: Can you show the $p values

Comment: Do you want single Pizza value or multiple??

Comment: @A.ANoman He's using show method where we generally retrieve  single value bro :)

Comment: @KhalidKhan Then He can use first() instead of get()

Comment: Please Try

$p=Pizza::where('p_name','prashant')->first();

Comment: @ShihabEK Bro I've already posted the answer below. Take a look at it once :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually You are using show method to fetch the data which suggests that your controller code should be like this:

```
public function show($id){
    $pizza = Pizza::where('p_name','prashant')->get()->first();
    return view('details')->with('pizza',$pizza);
}
```

And your view code should be like this

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Pizza List - {{$pizza->id}}
    </div> 
    {{$pizza->type}}  // This Will work now
</div>
```

Comment: thank you bro it worked!... also can you suggest me from where i can study laravel properly because in official site it is difficult for me to understand its language and implementation

Comment: @PrashantJani Bro can you mark my answer? And for laravel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiMYkrkXJ6k&list=PLpzy7FIRqpGD0kxI48v8QEVVZd744Phi4 Complete this seriesto get better understanding of it

Answer (score 0):

If you get single Pizza value then use this

```
$p=Pizza::where('p_name','prashant')->first();


<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Pizza List - {{$id}}
    </div> 
    {{$p->type}} 
</div>
```

And If you want multiple Pizza value then use this

```
$p=Pizza::where('p_name','prashant')->get();

<div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        Pizza List - {{$id}}
    </div> 
     @foreach($p as $pizza)
         {{$pizza->type}} 
     @endforeach
</div>
```